# How do I modify the options for the power button?

Tags: power-management

When I press the power button a dialog opens, but I want to shutdown the system without receiving "Do you really really want to shutdown?". How can I choose a direct shutdown action on a pressed power button?

I had the same problem with the 11.04 version, but I don't remember the solution and yesterday I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Lid Close Action**

To set up the Laptop Lid Close Action you have to install Advanced Setting (or the Gnome Tweak Tool).  It is in the USC (Ubuntu Software Center) under either tweak or Advanced Settings. If installed press the super button and type in tweak or advanced and choose the Advanced Settings.  When it opens choose the shell tab;

[image: Advanced Settings Before]

Press the arrows and choose you desired on both on AC and on battery;

[image: Advanced Setting After]

**Default buttons behavior**

Install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Press alt+f2 and open dconf-editor (or in a terminal type dconf-editor)

Navigate to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power and set your default button-power action there:

[image]

On some systems you will also need to mark the item `suppress-logout-restart-shutdown`.

Comment: This would be a solution... for Ubuntu 11.04. He's talking about Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: the answer is "fixed", its not a bug, its a "feature".

Comment: That's better :p

Comment: I am really wondering if this means userfriendly if you need to install some app and change reg-files to make something trivial like that working.

Comment: You can also use command lines for that, gsettings will do the job just fine. Its something that will be fixed soon I hope. Def not user friendly ;)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me on 11.10. It seems like it should, and there is a bug.

Comment: Note that you may also need to disable `logout-prompt` under `/org/gnome/gnome-session/`.

Comment: I can't even find the org folder. It's missing for some reason.

Comment: The GNOME team has now decided that [the shutdown option is "too destructive"](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/commit/69d9d8b1eda2d50acca5b4da58003afb8b82a7f1). Beware of upgrading to later versions of GNOME.

Comment: What would be the command line version of this? I believe it should be `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'shutdown'` for non-interactive shutdown, but it doesn't work for me, on 16.04. Meanwhile, the graphical solution does work! Could you please update the answer to include the command-line solution to make power button do non-interactive shutdown?

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 46):

I'm afraid that the first answers didn't work for me, I think that the 'graphical solutions' only work for the upper right indicator, not for the power button. rulet solution works for me, I think I can improve it and make the prompt completely disappear. Instead of creating a new file you can use existing `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
```

Add `#` to comment line:

```
#action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

Add a new line:

```
action=/sbin/poweroff
```

Save file. Open a console and type:

```
sudo acpid restart
```

That works for me AND the prompt has gone, just like in ubuntu 11.04. Wish this helps.

Comment: Thanks I've been looking all over the place for an answer to this. All the other stuff about gsettings doesn't work for me on 12.04 with gnome shell.

Comment: Yes! This is also the only thing that worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, this works on Ubuntu 13.04. Other answers involving gsettings do not work (I guess, any more).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 but to disable the prompt I had to set `button-power` option in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` in `dconf-editor` to `nothing`.

Comment: Worked for me on Xubuntu 16.04. Did not want to install any additional apps as first solution mentioned.

Comment: Note: there were other answers, that have been helpful. The most important thing though is to restart the acpi daemon (acpid). Furthermore sometimes you need to press the button (e.g. on my Zenbook UX32VDA) just a tiny bit longer in order for it to get caught by the system.

Comment: And this is what Linux is all about! Bypassing all the GUI mambo jumbo and making changes directly!

Answer (score 32):

This is the quick, simple answer I needed:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'hibernate'
```

If you want to see your settings first, try this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power
```

Or maybe this if you want to see all the power settings:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for on Ubuntu 11.10:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'suspend'

Comment: To revert this change use: gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'shutdown'` for non-interactive shutdown? It doesn't work for me, on 16.04, while the graphical solution with installing `dconf-editor` does.

Comment: to check that specific trigger press >$gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power

Comment: @Pav I think the 'get' option didn't work for me correctly in 2011.  It works in 16.10, so I added it to the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to change the power button to suspend-to-RAM. On a Ubuntu 14.04 server (no Gnome/X), changing `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` to use an alternate action (`/usr/sbin/pm-suspend`) did *not* work.

Instead, adding a single line to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` was enough to do the trick:

```
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandlePowerKey=suspend
```

Now, pressing the power button causes instant suspend.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04, Xmonad)

Comment: Odd, this did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS just now.  dconf-editor solution worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04.1

Comment: This was also the only thing that worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04 and awesome window manager.

Comment: Did not work from me, with Ubuntu 16.04.3 (neither from fluxbox nor from tty1)

Answer (score 9):

Bruno's answer is only half-correct.

After installing dconf, you should navigate to apps>indicator-session

Place a check mark for the item "suppress-logout-restart-shutdown."

This will work for Unity in Ubuntu 11.10 but not for Gnome 3 or Gnome Classic.

Comment: Your answer or the other answer will work in 11.10 but not Gnome3 or Classic?

Comment: Interestingly, I observe that this only affects the dialog popup when using the indicator in the uppper right. Pressing the power button still shows the dialog.

Answer (score 8):

That didn't work for me in unity or gnome-shell(prompt was always shown). So I've used [this manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Shutdown_Pressing_Power_Button)

from arch linux wiki. I've created file /etc/acpi/events/power with the content:

```
event=button/power (PWR.||PBTN)
action=/sbin/poweroff
```

and executed a command:

sudo acpid restart (don't know exactly if it's right command)

And then by pressing hardware power-button computer shotdowns(the prompt will be shown, but that won't stop shutdown process).

Comment: That is more helpful for headless command-line-only systems.

Comment: That is helpful for any type of systems.

Comment: wow, I went through every other answer above and this is the only one that actually worked. I'm on `Ubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 1):

For current Ubuntu and Lubuntu systems:

```
echo "HandlePowerKey=suspend" | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/logind.conf
sudo service systemd-logind suspend
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was was this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action suspend
```

Comment: Probably OK for standard Ubuntu using Gnome Shell, but the question was asked nine years ago and thus related to the Unity desktop.This may have changed in the mean time.

Comment: @vanadium gsettings attributes have been almost the same I think. Regardless of that, this question shows up in Google Search as the first one so this answer might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked on my 13.04 system. In the end I re-compiled **gnome-session**.

In **gsm_shell.c** and **gsm_logout_dialog.c** change 
`#define AUTOMATIC_ACTION_TIMEOUT from 60 to 5`