# How to shutdown the computer with physical power button or by closing the lid?

Tags: unity, 11.10, settings, power-management

Does anyone know how to fine tune power settings in 11.10 such that I can turn off the power immediately (no dialogue box) by pressing the physical power button or closing the lid? It was easy to do this in 11.04 and earlier versions, but in 11.10 the power settings are pretty minimal. I'm a bit of a GUI slave, so if this requires CLI I'll need some training wheels to guide me through it. Thanks for suggestions. My favourite thing about Ubuntu has always been the ease of customizing it, but with 11.10 it seems more and more difficult to point and click your way to a custom set up.

Comment: have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown)

Comment: @brunopereira81 Should have been an answer? Or listed as duplicate?

Comment: Well, the other post explains how to control the power settings (fine tune them) to your needs, its not an exact duplicate but can be answered using the other post.

Comment: moderators will make the decision, if you have a better answer for this please go ahead and do it, but maybe emend the other question to reflect more information / methods is a better advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lid Close Action**

To set up the Laptop Lid Close Action you have to install Advanced Setting (or the Gnome Tweak Tool).  It is in the USC (Ubuntu Software Center) under either tweak or Advanced Settings. If installed press the super button and type in tweak or advanced and choose the Advanced Settings.  When it opens choose the shell tab;

[image: Advanced Settings Before]

Press the arrows and choose you desired on both on AC and on battery;

[image: Advanced Setting After]

**Default buttons behavior**

Install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Press alt+f2 and open dconf-editor (or in a terminal type dconf-editor)

Navigate to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power and set your default button-power action there:

[image]

Comment: hope you don't mind the edit, that way we keep everything under 1 roof. Your answer was great btw, makes things so much simple.