# How do I set my laptop to shutdown instead of hibernating/suspending when I close the lid?

Tags: power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the power button to shutdown instantly instead of opening a dialog window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-set-the-power-button-to-shutdown-instantly-instead-of-opening-a-dialog)

I have a Dell M4300 and the hibernate/suspend dosn't work properly. Instead I would like to have it to shut down when I close the lid. I have not had this problem on earlier versions, but on 11.10 there is no option for shutdown on closing the lid in the powermanagement.

Comment: You're right. There isn't. You can file a bug about it on http://launchpad.net.