# How do I configure an action when pressing hardware power button?

Tags: 11.10, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [power button “instant”-shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown)

There is no option "action when pressing hardware power-button"(shutdown, hibernate, suspend) in ubuntu 11.10. Where to configure it in the system?

... I've found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown).