# How can I enable the power button on my server?

Tags: server, hardware, shutdown, acpi

The power button on my headless 11.10 server appears to do nothing unless I hold it in for 5 seconds or so, in which case it switches the machine off instantly.

What I'd like it to do if I press it briefly is a normal shutdown (`shutdown -P now`). How can I allow this?

I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown) but it is for desktop installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might need acpi-support. Check out the links below for more info on how to manipulate the power button press event.

http://blog.metalight.dk/2010/07/ubuntu-lucid-custom-power-button-event/

http://test.z13media.com/2010/03/disable-power-button-on-ubuntu-server.html

Comment: I don't have an `/etc/acpi/` directory, even after running `sudo apt-get install acpi`. Or am I supposed to just create it myself?

Comment: That's because you need the 'acpi-support' package, as said above. Don't think any of the acpi related ones are included in the server edition.

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Sorry, I misread your post initially.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @mikewhatever I presume you've implemented this power off feature. Does the server ask for user passwords or any such question or does it jsut shutdown directly?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to install `acpid` package (`sudo apt-get install acpid`), its just one package, nothing more and it will handle all powerbutton events (acpi-support contains more additional packages). Tested on ubuntu server 11.10

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2011-November/253766.html