# Lid closed power option doesn't work anymore

Tags: 11.10, power-management, lenovo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify the power options in Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options-in-ubuntu-11-10)

After upgrade to 11.10 the lid close option in the power settings doesnt seem to work anymore. Only options now are hibernate or suspend, but both don't seem to work.
I now have to shut down manualy.

Any ideas ?

Comment: @brunopereira81 I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: Really dont see the confusion here, unless the user has an out of scope question or a bug in his system that other answer should allow him to configure all the "close lid" actions possible with and including overriding the confirmation dialog when you want to shutdown.