# How-to specify power button to do a 'shutdown -h now' instead of graphical shutdown menu?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I would like to specify that when I press the power button in my laptop, a 'shutdown -h now' command is sent, instead of bringing up the graphical shutdown menu. How can I do that on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the power button to shutdown instantly instead of opening a dialog window?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-set-the-power-button-to-shutdown-instantly-instead-of-opening-a-dialog)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's simple enough. When you press the power button a ACPI event triggers the script at `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`.

You can edit that to just run `shutdown -h now` as the first thing so it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
# Initiates a shutdown when the power putton has been
# pressed.

/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
exit 0

# leave the old code below (in case you want to revert!)
```

Comment: Move your answer to the other one and we can close this as a dupe.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 as well.