# Ubuntu suspends when the lid is closed after pressing shutdown

Tags: shutdown, suspend

I am running 12.10. Usually when I am in a hurry I press the shutdown button on the bar and close the lid of my laptop just after that. Often, I observe that instead of shutting down, the system suspends (because I closed the lid right after) and the shut down process resumes after I reopen the lid which wakes it up.

Is there any workaround such that once the shutdown button has been pressed, Ubuntu does not allow "suspension on lid close" and it carries out the shutdown (and not the sleep) even if the lid is pulled down right after the shutdown button is pressed?

Also, I don't want to switch off the "sleep on lid close" feature either.

Comment: This might be an issue unique to lightdm. Perhaps gdm will not have this problem..

Comment: May be any logout script delay the process.

Comment: I have observed the same behavior on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: I think you have a process that is slowing down shutdown. Have you tried looking in the shutdown logs or whatever they are called ?

Comment: manage your time better so you are not in such a hurry?

Comment: @PavelA It's default behavior for Windows 7. It follows the spirit of "if shutting down is taking to much time, close the lid and you can put it away anyhow".

Comment: Does it still this behaviour if you wait like 1-2s, when Unity is closed?

Comment: @labsin, it actually may be convenient. Especially when installing updates, which can take up quite a bit.

Comment: @PavelA: Yes, for Windows indeed. (as it can't update itself while running for some reason, or desperately ones to do it when you shut it down)

Comment: You should change the setting that controls when it shuts down. Sorry if it dosn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, subscribe to it and wait till it's fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/471457

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this line `sleep 5` bellow `#!/bin/bash` in file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`.

Second possibility is edit `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` as following and old content leave below as backup (this is from this question [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86376/how-to-specify-power-button-to-do-a-shutdown-h-now-instead-of-graphical-shutd))

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
# Initiates a shutdown when the power putton has been
# pressed.

/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
exit 0

# leave the old code below (in case you want to revert!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to change the suspend option when lid is closed. Change the lid close option to nothing. The shutdown process was initiated first but some process delays it and mean while when you close the lid it gets suspended.