# How do I get Ubuntu to ignore power button presses?

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I've got a small media server that sits under my TV, and it runs Ubuntu 11.04 desktop x64 with XBMC on top. I've got a problem in that unknowing users / visitors occasionally press the power button 'just to see what happens'. Ubuntu dutifully intercepts this and either sleeps or halts.

This is really annoying.

One possible option is to just disconnect the power button from the motherboard, as I've done with the reset button. However, I'd still like to be able to power it back on if I choose to `halt` it myself, for whatever reason, or if it completely locks up.

How can I get Ubuntu to effectively 'ignore' people randomly prodding at the power button while it's turned on?

Comment: Possible duplicate? (http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-set-the-power-button-to-shutdown-instantly-instead-of-opening-a-dialog) - its probably the dconf-editor setting in that answer.

Comment: wouldn't call that a duplicate as the problems are differently described, although the answer is universal enough for both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Bruno Pereira has made a [thorough post](https://askubuntu.com/a/66731/16981) about the power button and how to customize the actions.
In short:
By using dconf-editor (either you'll have it or you'll need to install it) and navigate to org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power and choose power-button as blank.

Comment: I just tried to follow this, and noticed that I don't have a `settings-daemon` entry under `org.gnome`. `gnome-settings-daemon` is installed, but not running.

Comment: uhm, I'm not sure at this point.
What do you mean by not running? does it have equivalent entrier such as plugins/power?