# How do I suppress the confirmation dialogue when ending a session?

Tags: 11.10

I currently using an old PC with Ubuntu 11.10. When I want to restart(or turn off) the system Ubuntu always ask me for confirmation.

I want to force it to perform immediately and don't want to see any confirmation dialogue anymore.

How can I suppress that?

Answer (score 2):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power suppress_logout_restart_shutdown true
```

Will remove the box with the action confirmation that shows up when you press the shutdown button in Ubuntu 11.10

To re-enable it use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power suppress_logout_restart_shutdown false
```

For more information on how to setup your power options and different power button actions visit the following post

- [How do I modify the options for the power button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options-in-ubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu Tweak from Software Center,[image],
Click on Tweaks,

Click on Session Control,[image]

Check Supress Dialog to confirm Logout Restart Shutdown.