# Disable shutdown confirmation for physical "Power off" button in the dash (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, hardware

On my notebook in the dash (above the keyboard) there is physical button for turning the computer on and off.

How to set up this button to turn off the system immediately without confirmation? Where is the handler for this button? Or how to create it and use? I want to put to it `systemctl poweroff`.

There is the similar question - [Disable shutdown confirmation ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272300/disable-shutdown-confirmation-ubuntu-20-04) but it is not only about setting up the physical "Power off" button. For configuring `Shutdown`/`Reboot` menu items in system menu `Bring Out Sub Menu Extension` can be used as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232696/1548713).
Moreover [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272316/1548713) in this question is not working - I tried it. Also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272305/1548713) explains that the solution must be another.

Please do not suggest to me:

- To press to the button and wait a minute.
- To make keyboard shortcut.

I have "Power button" and I want to make use of it. Or at least to know that this is impossible in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution**

I found working solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279591/1548713) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/78563/1548713):

- Create file:

`sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`

with the content:

```
event=button/power (PWR.||PBTN)
action=/sbin/poweroff
```

- Then restart the `acpi` daemon with:

`sudo acpid restart`

- Try to use "Power off" button.

---

Related links:

- [PowerManagement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement#Handling_hardware_events)
- [sudo shutdown vs pressing power button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170155/sudo-shutdown-vs-pressing-power-button)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/84984/1548713

---

**Second solution**

Also I tested [the answer of Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392912/1548713) and confirm that this recommendations is also working.

Answer (score 1):

For GNOME Desktop, in your terminal run

```
hostnamectl set-chassis vm
```

then reboot.  After the system reboots it should work where the power button will now power off the system without asking.

To set it back run

```
hostnamectl set-chassis desktop
```

same as above, reboot the system then it should start asking again about shutting down.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Terrance, thanks. I just tested everything in your answer and confirm that all works as you described (only not tested for the second user). Thanks for the solution!
I'm curious what command gets executed under this `VM chassis mark` to reboot the system? And where this command is configured? May it can be customized?

Comment: For me, it works only if the monitor ever gets connected. Otherwise (if the monitor wasn't ever connected since power on), the power button is just ignored.