# How to configure sh handler for physical poweroff button?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, button, gnome-power-manager

How to make sh script and run it when physical poweroff button is pressed?
How to remove standard handler with user confirmation for this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To remove standard handler with user confirmation for poweroff button:**

- Install `dconf` editor: `sudo apt install -y dconf-cli dconf-editor`
- Run `dconf`
- Set option `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/power-button-action` to `nothing`.
- To check its value in console:
  `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | grep power-button-action`
- Configuration for this setting will be stored in user home directory.

**To set up physical poweroff button handler:**

Create sh script:

- `sudo touch /etc/acpi/poweroff.sh`
- `sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/poweroff.sh`
- `sudo vim /etc/acpi/poweroff.sh`
- Put to it the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE='/var/log/poweroff.log'
#touch $LOG_FILE && chmod 0666 $LOG_FILE
touch $LOG_FILE && chmod a=rw $LOG_FILE
echo "$(date '+%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'): poweroff button pressed, event: $1" >> $LOG_FILE
sudo systemctl poweroff
```

For example, the following commands can be used for corresponding actions:

- `sudo systemctl poweroff`
- `sudo systemctl suspend`
- `sudo systemctl hibernate`
- `sudo systemctl reboot`

Create poweroff physical button event handler:

- `sudo touch /etc/acpi/events/power`
- `sudo vim /etc/acpi/events/power`
- Put to it the following content:

```
event=button/power LNXPWRBN
action=/etc/acpi/poweroff.sh "%e"
```

Apply changes:

- `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart`

When the button is pressed new line will be added to the log file

`sudo less /var/log/poweroff.log`

```
2022.02.24 02:14:55.322: poweroff button pressed, event: button/power PBTN 00000080 00000000
2022.02.24 02:14:55.327: poweroff button pressed, event: button/power LNXPWRBN:00 00000080 00000014
```

Related link: [Disable shutdown confirmation for physical "Power off" button in the dash (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392904/disable-shutdown-confirmation-for-physical-power-off-button-in-the-dash-ubunt)