# How to add "shutdown" to the list of "when the lid is closed" in power settings?

Tags: power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify the power options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options)

I'd like to shutdown my laptop by closing the lid; but in Power Settings there's no option to do that.

Is there any way to add "shutdown" to the pop-down list in the power settings for "when the lid is closed"? I prefer the way through the terminal without installing a third-party application.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/66723/83046.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add this option to the menu, because it is a hard coded list of options. You would have to write a script runs in the background that detects the lid being closed and activates the shutdown automatically.

The command you need (to check to see if the lid is closed is):

`cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state`

Now, I'm no scripting junkie (bash scripting I mean), so maybe someone can edit this and give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you Roland for the start point. I'll keep searching.

Comment: @AliNa: does the answer here: [How do I modify the power options in Ubuntu 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/66723) work for you?

Comment: Oh, yes :)) this function works properly in 12.04.1. But I guess some others may not work; for example, changing "Windows > Action on title-bar middle-click" doesn't.

Comment: @AliNa: some features will not work, but I was specifically asking about the shutdown on lid close option.