# Shutdown functions

Tags: shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify the power options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options)
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

On Windows was a function to not shut down completely, but save the session in RAM to start directly form where you end it. I used the "turn on"- button of my Laptop to exit the laptop that way. Can i program the button on Ubuntu if there's something like that?