# "Shut Down" and "Restart" from system (drop-down) menu inactive

Tags: power-management

The "Shut Down" and "Restart" options from the menu (see image below) are not responsive (nothing happens after I click either of them). A few minutes after launching Ubuntu the "Restart" option disappears.
How to restore the default.

My platform: Ubuntu 13.10

[image]

Comment: What is your question?! you need how to repair or how to do it command line?!

Comment: How to repair it?

Answer (score 2):

I found out a solution with "dconf":

- Install the "dconf-editor" from USC (ubuntu sofware center).
- Launch the dconf from the dash
- Press a combine Ctrl+f, on the "search box" type: "shutdown" then you will see the "supress-logout-restart-shutdown", tick it for a mark.

[reference here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options)

This solves my trouble, but exactly as in the name: "supress....", it will shutdown or restart your session right after you press the "indicator append session" without asking for confirmation.

So that's another issue - how can I get it to ask for confirmation before shutdown or restart to prevent losing unsaved data?