# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit - computer shuts down by itself

Tags: 64-bit, shutdown, 14.04, thinkpad

After I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on my Lenovo ThinkPad T61 today, I could boot up Ubuntu without problem but after I run the Software Center, Additional Driver, or Firefox, the computer will shut itself down. Could it be possible that the 64-bit version is not compatible? I used to use 12.04 32-bit without any problems.

Comment: How it shuts down? Suddenly or you get to see ubuntu screen?

Comment: Hi Cornelius, I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell N5110, and I seem to be having the same problem. While using Android Studio or Firefox, the computer suddenly shows the Ubuntu screen(with the 4 circles). Do you happen to have any solutions, or clue as to why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's the likely cause, if your computer was incompatible with 64-bit linux (x86_64) it would not boot at all. I would check the fans, it may be overheating. You might also check the [power settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options).

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I checked the CPU temp and found that it's really the fan problem. It's quite a coincidence that it broke the same day I upgraded the OS.

Comment: @CESILICON It's more common then you might think. It's [Finagle's corollary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finagle%27s_law).

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too. It just shuts down at random intervals. What I did is:

- Clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04
- Remove Unknown Display.
- Update
- Broadcom Additional Driver
- Ubuntu Restricted Extras

When I installed the Additional Driver for my Nvidia GT520 it also randomly froze the screen and I had to go back to the x.org.

I think that I'll have to go back to the 13.10 until this is solved as Ubuntu 14.04 is unusable as it is right now.

Comment: Ok, I kind of figured what is wrong in mine. A couple of years ago the Delete key in my laptot's keyboard went out fliying and ever since I have been using it just by placing my finger where it used to be... there is no key, but somehow the contact worked.
I have been doing so with ubuntu 10.04 all the way to 13.10 and windows 7 and 8 without any problem, but now with 14.04 when I touch it the pc shuts down immediately with a 'puffff' sound. I wonder what's changed

Comment: Solved with a 0,6x0,6 cm of adhesive tape. Not fancy, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced random shutdowns / restarts in Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04.

While watching Youtube it mostly shuts down. I also play some flash player games in browser. I tried different environment - LXDE , Unity , Gnome , etc but it was never solved. Even cleaned fan vents, without opening, by blowing air through straw. Always kept laptop in power saving mode still it had shutdown.

At last found out that addition of extra RAM made total RAM Ghz greater than CPU Ghz causing excess heat to CPU resulting in shutdown.

After unplugging, of additional 4 GB RAM module, no more shutdowns because of heat.

32 bit OS limits RAM usage by its own, only 64 bit OS uses full RAM and heats CPU if CPU capacity is lesser than RAM capacity.