# How to change mapping for the «PowerOff» key on keyboard?

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys

I've bought the ROG G551JM Asus laptop which proven to be Ubuntu-compatible. The computer's keyboard is ill-designed with the key "Poweroff" being an ordinary key, placed in the spot, where one usually finds the "End" key. The computer is fine otherwise, so I bought it with the assumption, that I would be able to somehow "fix" the problem, i.e. remap the PowerOff button into the "End" key.

*The PowerOff button made wrong (ASUS G551JM):*
[image: ASUS G551JM]

*Normally there is an «End» key (ASUS N56VZ):*
[image: ASUS N56VZ]

The "PowerOff" button events are produced by the `/dev/input/event2:    Power Button` device (as reported by `evtest`) with code 116 (example line from `evtest`: `Event: time 1422895638.246142, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 116 (KEY_POWER), value 1`)

The key is also visible to X server, and ultimately Ubuntu can identify key presses as a `PowerOff` key and launches the "Goodbye user Adam..." semi-transparent dialog box that confirms my will to actually turn the computer off.

The problem is that the binding that binds the PowerOff key press with the routine that displays that confirmation dialog is not visible under dconf-editor and I have no hint where to find it.

**Can anyone tell me, where to change (or delete) the default binding for the PowerOff key???**

It should be something easy.

---

edit 21.IX.2016:

There is a way to permanently disable the dialog box, see [How do I modify the options for the power button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-options-for-the-power-button) . I hope that after disabling the power button, it would be possible to re-assign it to something else.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? It would be very useful if you post an answer here.

Comment: @Ezze Not really (I am using different computer because of this issue). But I managed to permanently disablethe shutdown dialog produced after pressing the key. OK, I'll update the answer.

Comment: [Related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106468/52745) on Unix & Linux StackExchange.

Comment: I hate ASUS so much for removing that key. `Home` and `End` are the "meta" keys I use the most... :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to get it working on my ASUS N751JK in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (tested with Unity desktop environment in both cases and KDE Plasma in 18.04):

1. First of all, set action of *"Power Off"* button to `nothing`.

   **Unity**

   Like mentioned in answer of [Johano Fierra](https://askubuntu.com/users/311527/johano-fierra):

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power "nothing"
   ```

   or alternatively `sudo apt install dconf-tools` and use `dconf-editor` to change `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` property (like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/66731/63516)). Reboot or logout is required to make it working.

   **KDE**

   Go to *"System Settings"*, select *"Power Management"* tab in *"Hardware"* section and then select *"Energy Saving"* tab, scroll down, find *"When power button pressed"* dropdown list and change its value to *"Do nothing"*. Click *"Apply"* button for changes to take an effect.

   [image: Energy saving]
2. Install [xdotool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdotool):

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```

   This one will allow us to trigger key events.
3. Next step is to trigger *"End"* key press on *"Power off"* button press.

   **Ubuntu 18.04**

   Create `/etc/acpi/events/power` file with the following contents:

   ```
   event=button/power
   action=/etc/acpi/power.sh "%e"
   ```

   and create `/etc/acpi/power.sh` script with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   xdotool key End
   ```

   and add execution permissions to it:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/power.sh
   ```

   **Ubuntu 16.04**

   Backup ACPI script used to handle *"Power Off"* button's event:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.backup
   ```

   Then edit it, find the following:

   ```
   # If logind is running, it already handles power button presses; desktop
   # environments put inhibitors to logind if they want to handle the key
   # themselves.
   ```

   and modify the code below so it looks like:

   ```
   if pidof systemd-logind >/dev/null; then
       xdotool key End
       exit 0
   fi
   ```
4. In order to apply these changes one should run:

   ```
   sudo acpid restart
   ```

   Thanks to [Adam](https://askubuntu.com/users/55241/adam-ryczkowski) it's possible to restart `acpid` automatically when a user logs in (on system boot). So instead of manual `sudo acpid restart` in terminal each time after reboot add the following line:

   ```
   session optional    pam_exec.so /usr/sbin/acpid restart
   ```

   to the end of `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file.

Comment: What about `sudo acpid reload` instead of restart? Would that work?

Comment: `sudo acpid reload` also works for me when I run it manually in terminal. But it doesn't help when I place `acpid reload` in `/etc/rc.local` or in bash script specified by LightDM's `session-setup-script`.

Comment: @Ezze Have you tried restarting / reloading acpid in `Startup Applications`?

Comment: I tried to add `acpid restart` to `Startup Applications` but it also doesn't work. According to [this topic](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980891) startup applications are not running under `root` user (what is required to restart `acpid`).

Comment: What solves the `acpid restart` problem is to add a line `session optional pam_exec.so /usr/sbin/acpid restart` at the end of `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. This way the acpid will get restarted just after user login and this is just enough for me. Problem solved at last!!

Comment: `$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power
'nothing'` - Even though power is mapped to nothing, my power button still puts the laptop to sleep. What am I missing - Asus UX501V on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @rtindru, you should `gsettings set` instead of `gsettings get`.

Comment: Ah, I feel stupid for not seeing this. Thanks @Ezze, works!

Comment: In order to make this work in Kubuntu 18.04, I had to give execution permissions to power.sh:
```sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/power.sh```
@Ezze, maybe you could update your answer to include this.

Comment: +1. You don't need a `power.sh` script, though. Just put invoke the `xdotool` in the `action`, like so: `action=xdotool key End`

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick.

Enter in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power "nothing"
```

Comment: YES!!! But then there is another thing: how to map it into the «end» key?

Comment: Entering uncharted territory here, but I think you could just create a xmodmap file config (${HOME}/.xmodmap) and then put this in it: **keycode  116 = End**, or enter in terminal: **xmodmap -e "keycode  116 = End"**

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. It disables capturing of "Power off" button as it seen by `xev` command and prevents `xmodmap` to remap it. And by the way, "Power off" button's keycode may be different (124 for my ASUS N751JK).

Comment: It should not disable the ability to capture the button... but how about this. Enter in terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power "shutdown"` (so pressing the button is captured), then edit `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` and comment out the line `#action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`, and then enter in terminal: `xmodmap -e "keycode 124 = End"` This should prevent the power button from doing anything and in the same time map it to the End key.

Comment: It doesn't help too cause "Power off" event is handled not only by `powerbtn.sh` script but also by (at least) `systemd-logind` service (probably, it uses `button-power` setting you mentioned in your answer). You can find `if pidof systemd-logind >/dev/null; then`...`exit 0` line in `powerbtn.sh` which means that the script lets `systemd-logind` to handle "Power off" event by itself when desktop session is active. One thing you are right about — changing `button-power` value doesn't affect the ability to capture the key but it's already captured by some process (`systemd-logind` or other).