# Remap keys with modifiers on Ubuntu 18.04 Wayland

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, wayland, remapping

I am the (sad) owner of an otherwise-nice ASUS laptop where ASUS decided that it would be a great idea to replace the <kbd>End</kbd> key by <kbd>Power</kbd>, so you could accidentally poweroff your laptop when mispressing <kbd>PgDn</kbd> (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580902/how-to-change-mapping-for-the-poweroff-key-on-keyboard) for the photo)...

I initially wanted to use the numeric keypad <kbd>Home/7</kbd> and <kbd>End/1</kbd>, and it works (when Num lock is off), but when I press <kbd>Shift + Home</kbd>, to select the whole line, I get `7` ... unless Num lock is on, but then I get `7` instead of Home.

So I used remapped the keys with `xmodmap` to get <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> behaviour with all modifiers:

```
keycode  79      = Home Home Home Home U2196 U21D6
keycode  87      = End End End End U2199 U21D9
```

Unfortunately, it's not working anymore since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 with Wayland. Worse: it's actually working in Firefox but not in Eclipse...

I read many posts about different remapping techniques that were either outdated or too complex to put in place. Now that `xmodmap` is kind of deprecated, is there an equivalent in Wayland to remap keys *with modifiers* (I would be happy with <kbd>(Shift+)Fn+key</kbd> too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped using "Ubuntu on Wayland" as the Display Server and chose "Ubuntu" instead (which is on X11, where `xmodmap` is working fine).

But I would be really glad to switch back to Wayland (or until I change my laptop).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, in case someone needs a quick recipe for swapping keys on Wayland (done on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I've got a dumb layout on my notebook keyboard, and needed to swap the "right shift" and the "?" keys. So, following the advice from https://askubuntu.com/a/1023182/976363 I simply edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` as root, swapping the keycodes for both keys.

```
    <RTSH> = 62;
    ...
    <AB11> = 97;
```

became

```
    <RTSH> = 97;
    ...
    <AB11> = 62;
```

The actual key labels depend on your keyboard layout, which should be looked up in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.

Comment: Sounds so straightforward... I'll try to check that tomorrow and will get back to you asap. Though it might mess things up of you plug an external keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I believe any external keyboard would get the same remapping as well.

Comment: Some lines have a `defined` section, like this: `<I171> = 171; // #define KEY_NEXTSONG            163` . How do I edit this line?

Comment: It seems that `//` starts a standard comment, so you can just ignore it.

The `#define` part looks to be from the `input.h` [header file from the Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h), so it is just documenting the key code mapping between Linux terminal and X11...