# Nothing happens when i press the power button

Tags: power-management, gedit, button

When i press the power button on my desktop it used to suspend but now it seems that nothing happens.

Would the fix be under `sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know exactly what might be the problem, but try to go to keyboard shortcuts, create new shortcut with for example "sudo sleep" and when assigning shortcut, press power button - it should say XF86PowerOff.  In my case it gives me choice to shutdown, sleep or restart...

Comment: because button is probably assigned for other task than sudo sleep. But when it does nothing, it might help...

Comment: And this might help as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-options-for-the-power-button/66731#66731