# How to change Power-Button to Suspend in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, power-management

I know the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/66731/25388) about *How do I modify the options for the power button?* However, the dconf-editor is completely different than in previous versions. There is no *Settings-daemon*. 
It looks like this

[image]

---

How can you change power-button to be Suspend in 16.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is best if you set it via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power suspend
```

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 7):

In Dconf editor go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power[image]